# Unique ContextMenu for each TreeItem

Tags: treeview, contextmenu, javafx

I can set ContextMenu for a TreeView through the custom cellFactory, but the problem is that this menu is applied to all items in the tree. Is there are an way to bind different contextMenus to different items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By design, the custom `TreeCell` you have defined will be reused multiple times while rendering the tree view item values and it is good thing. In `updateItem` method, you can change the content of the "current" contextMenu according to the item passed as parameter to this `updateItem` method.